# Linux Mint, is there a captive-portal software for?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, authentication, hostapd

Does Linux Mint 17+ has a software for doing captive portal?

Amongst the provided list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal),
it seems none is mint-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Debian- and Ubuntu-compatible software should be ok.

Googleing "captive portal ubuntu" gave me CoovaChilli.

Comment: I am googling, oh yes, trust me. What is the most used though ? CoovaChill under testing...